# How to calculate the linux kernel 0x07c0 address?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am reading a book about linux.It says the address 0x7c00 is about 31K.I want to know how to get the 31K according to address.The code is:mov ax,#BOOTSEG.Which #BOOTSEG is 0x07c0.I have already search from internet.

Comment: Do you know how to convert between hexadecimal notation and decimal? And it's closer to 31K than 37K. 31744, to be exact.

Comment: It's possible the book is just wrong.  Could you clarify your question?  Is it how to get 37K from 0x7c00?  Is it why one place says 0x7c00 but the other says 0x07c0?

Comment: @twalberg It is my fault.It is 31K.

Comment: @Peter I am wrong.I am just calculate the address to 01....，and convert to precise addrese.It is 31K.

Comment: If you still have a question, edit the information back into the post, and clarify exactly what your question is.